# I want to know the conditions for running the newly added extension in the activity bar

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, vscode-extensions

VS Code has an activity bar with icons for opening the sidebar, such as debug, find, etc. In addition to the existing ones, I added an icon called test in the Java extension, and I want to open this icon with a shortcut.

[image: Activity bar image]

So, I added the following in keybindings.json, but it did not work. I wonder if this function does not work because the Source is the user or if the value is wrong.

```xml
{
    "key": "shift+cmd+t",
    "command": "workbench.view.extension.test",
    "when": "viewContainer.workbench.view.testing.enabled"
}
```

The conditions in **"when"** are the same as those previously applied to other icons.

```xml
{
    "key": "shift+cmd+d",
    "command": "workbench.view.debug",
    "when": "viewContainer.workbench.view.debug.enabled"
}
```

In conclusion, what I want to know is how to set the condition **"when"** registering a shortcut for the test icon.

Comment: search in the keybindings dialog for a command with `viewname.focus`, viewname is the name you give to your view in your bar

Comment: I found the dialog like the one below, but if I use the keyword testing here, the shortcut doesn't work.
`// - workbench.view.testing.focus`

It seems that `"when": "viewContainer.workbench.view.debug.enabled"` does not apply to icons added from extension.

Comment: what do you mean with `added an icon` and `open this icon with a shortcut`, if there is no view added to the bar you can't open it

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, what I was trying to say is, as you can see from the picture in the question above, the activity bar has icons, and there are basically **Explorer**, **Search** and **Run and debug**. All three of these icons have the same condition as `"viewContainer.workbench.view.debug.enabled"`. However, if condition `"viewContainer.workbench.view.testing.enabled"` is applied to newly added **Testing**, the shortcut key does not work. So I'm curious as to why the shortcut doesn't work because of the difference.

Answer (score 1):

This `when` clause should work for both the test commands.

```
{
    "key": "shift+cmd+t",
    // "command": "workbench.view.testing.focus",
    "command": "workbench.view.extension.test",
    "when": "workbench.view.testing.active"
}
```